# How to negotiate additional compensation for completing a "hard" project?

Tags: raise, compensation, software

Some months ago, my employer told me it would be nice if the devices we develop would have 4G network compatibility. These devices are quite old now and need newer options for data transmission. I am bringing this idea to reality all by myself and my employer is quite happy about it.

I want to be obviously at a higher economical position than before once I finish this project. My employer has never talked about an economical reward once the project is finished, neither have I asked him about my reward. This is not an easy project and I'm the only programmer here. I don't want to do this "free of charge" just because I'm a programmer, and I am employed here.

How should I let him know that I want to negotiate how much money I'll get out of this project? What would be the most ideal and realistic money offering for this kind of project? A percentage share of all devices installed monthly, or a one-off big payment?

Comment: This is your job, you're already being paid to do it

Comment: You don't want "compensation". You want a bonus.

Comment: If you want compensation for work, start by returning your salary. THEN you can ask for "compensation".

Comment: If 4G networking on your devices is a total market flop that ends up costing your company $$beaucoup, how much of your salary are you going to give back?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are doing this project outside of working hours then you are already being compensated. Going above and beyond was your choice. The work you are doing will be a huge plus when review time comes around. If you find a new position within the company has opened up you can use that side project in your interview. For the most part you don't really have room to ask for more pay just because you wrote some cool software.

Think of it this way. A researcher pushes towards the future with new and exciting breakthroughs in science but they don't get to say. "Hey boss I wont more money because I found this cool new drug you are going to make lots of money on". Its the researchers job to work towards the future.

All that being said. If you are working on this project outside of work you may be able to ask for compensation for all the extra time you spend on the project but it is unlikely they will say yes. Doesn't hurt to ask though.